# Why is my Control not being copied (or at least not visible)?

Tags: c#, dynamic, controls, clone, flowlayoutpanel

I am trying to clone a FlowLayoutPanel (including, of course, everthing on it - several different controls) and insert it onto a TabPage. tabPageRow0 (a TabPage control) has a FlowLayoutPanle named "panelRow0" on it. I want to copy it and place it on a different TabPage. Yet stepping through the code:

```
private void buttonShowMockupOfAllRows_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control tabpageCtrl = this.tabControl1.Controls["tabPageRow0"];
    TabPage tp = tabpageCtrl as TabPage;
    FlowLayoutPanel flp0 = tp.Controls["panelRow0"] as FlowLayoutPanel;

    tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPageUniMockup;
    TabPage tpMockup = tabControl1.SelectedTab;
    tpMockup.Controls.Add(flp0);
}
```

...although none of the objects are null, the FlowLayoutPanel is not visible on the TabPage. Why not?

### UPDATE

The (FlowLayoutPanel) Control *is* being added, apparently, because I altered the code to this:

```
. . .
MessageBox.Show(tpMockup.Controls.Count.ToString());
tpMockup.Controls.Add(flp0);
MessageBox.Show(tpMockup.Controls.Count.ToString());
```

...and I see first "1", then "2" - but why is it so shy and retiring?

### UPDATE 2

What is even odder (is "odder" a word? If it isn't, it odder be) is that after this code runs, the FlowLayoutPanel has disappeared from its original location. How could/why would that be?

### UPDATE 3

I don't know the answer to my question, so I'm not posting this as an answer, but it is the solution to my problem (IOW, I don't care much about my question any more):

```
private void buttonShowMockupOfAllRows_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control tabpageCtrl = this.tabControl1.Controls["tabPageRow0"];
    TabPage tp = tabpageCtrl as TabPage;
    FlowLayoutPanel flp0 = tp.Controls["panelRow0"] as FlowLayoutPanel;

    tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPageUniMockup;
    Image img = PanelToBitmap(flp0);
    pictureBox1.Image = img;
}

// From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181886/how-to-get-a-windows-forms-panel-as-a-bitmap-with-c
private static Image PanelToBitmap(Control pnl)
{
    var bmp = new Bitmap(pnl.Width, pnl.Height);
    pnl.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
    return bmp;
}
```

It works - as this is a mockup, I don't need the controls, I just need to see what the controls look like, and this does the trick.

Comment: I don't see any "cloning" code in your sample... (not a single `new XXXX`). Are you sure you've posted correct code?

Comment: Perhaps my terminology is faulty or awkward - I want to "copy-and-paste," so to speak.

Comment: You probably should change "clone" to "copy code" or something like that... Side note: Adding control to 2 different child collections at run-time will not cause anything but trouble.

Comment: I reckon you're right about that (See Update 2)